# Установить переменную jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, переменные, форма

Есть форма с автоматической отправкой. Вне формы есть дивы, которые имеют некое значение. Как мне скопировать в форму это значение? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Что значит "дивы имеют некое значение"? Что такое автоматическая отправка? Очень запутанный вопрос, на который вопросов больше чем ответов.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#element_id').val();   // Берет значение элемента с id="element_id"

$('#element_id2').val( 'value' ); // Присваивает полю с id="element_id2" значение value
```

**UPD 2013-06-24:**
Если не известен заранее идентификатор объекта, то можно "обернуть" все div в один какой-то общий div с уникальным идентификатором, напр. id="block_all".

Т.е.:

```
<div id="block_all">
        <div id='id_1'></div>
        <div id='id_2'></div>
        <div id='id_3'></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      var divs = $('div#block_all > div');
      for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
         console.log(divs[i].id);
      }
})
</script>
```

В консоли выведутся все нужные id.

Можно заменить console.log(divs[i].id) на alert(divs[i].id), кому как привычнее.

Comment: вроде бы то но id=имеет цифровое значение и неизвестное заранее, его нужно скопировать в поле input в value.

Comment: можно onclick="add(некое_число)" как вставить в форму это число

Comment: Ну можно попробовать например так:
Оберни все свои div в один какой-то общий и задай ему свой уникальный идентификатор, напр. id="block_all". 
Тогда:
`
// Занесем все div которые внутри div'a с id="block_all"
var divs = $('div#block_all > div');

// перебор результатов
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
      console.log(divs[i].id);
}
`
В консоли увидишь все свои id. 
// Либо замени console.log(divs[i].id); на alert(divs[i].id) 
// Кому как привычнее.


А вот про onclick="add(некое_число)" извини, не поняла сути вопроса...

Answer (score 2):

```
$(%form%).beforeSend(function(){
    //Доступ к данным елемента формы (input, textarea, и т.д.)
    $(%element%).val();

    //Доступ к обычным елементам
    $(%element%).html();

    //Простенький примерчик
    $(this).append($('input'));
});
```